# Some notebooks for complex analysis from Wolfram Mathworld website are not 100 % working?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, compatibility, version-12.3

For my study in Complex Analysis i like to study those two notebooks.
Can they be fixed, because it seems they are broken ?

- Branch Cut https://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/Calculus/BranchCut.nb
- Riemann Surface
  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/ComplexAnalysis/RiemannSurface.nb

Comment: How exactly are they broken? Can you be more specific? What version are you using? Many missing pieces information that are helpful for answering your questions

Comment: Its MMA 12.3 that i am using.
When i evaluate those two notebooks, then it seems that not all commands can be executed for a wanted output

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions in one post. The needed procedures to update this 2 notebooks are quite different.

Comment: The BranchCut notebook looks like it's missing some definitions.  The RiemannSurface notebook works fine in version 5.2 once you remove references to LiveGraphics3D.  The change in graphics commands from version 5.2 to version 12 are probably not worth the effort to convert, but will need to do quite a bit of studying of old graphics commands to convert a very short notebook.

Comment: If the creator Eric Weistein would update his notebooks, then the problem is solved.
I did another search for keyword Branch on Wolfram site, but yielded nothing for the complex analysis.
Am I not looking right yet ?

Comment: Then do you search *branch* in this site?

Comment: That's a good idea !